# Turn off filling in page number automatically for \autocite or \cite

Tags: biblatex

As I am quite sure, if I do `\autocite[23]{someref}`, I will get something along the lines of "[12, p. 23]". The problem comes when I am citing a section, for example I want "[12, II.2]", but if I use `\autocite[II.2]{someref}`, it comes up as "[12, p. II.2]" which I don't want. How do I get rid of the automatic addition of "p."?

Comment: Do you mean to disable it completely, or just to inhibit it for a particular citation? If the latter: `\autocite[\nopp II.2]{someref}`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To inhibit the pagination for a particular citation, you can use `\nopp` like:

```tex
\autocite[\nopp II.2]{someref}
```